# Laravel / PHP data filtering with many time

Tags: php, laravel

I've database like this

```
+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|     day    |        start_time          |          end_time         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Sunday  |       01:00                |         03:00             |
|    Sunday  |       13:00                |         15:00             |
|    Sunday  |       19:00                |         21:00             |
+------------+----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

and for checking date, i do with looping

```
// **nowTime = 02:00**
$get = DateModel::find($id)->get();
foreach($get as $result){
     if(nowTime >= $result->start_time && nowTime <= $result->end_time){
         echo "in range time";
     }else{
         echo "not in range time";
     }
}
```

and the result :

```
in range time  not in range time  not in range time
```

i just want only show 1 result if there have "in range time" ,

and if all data not in range time, go to else.

any idea ?

Comment: Use a simple flag that you initialize before the loop, `$inRange = false;` Inside the loop, set it to true, if you find a match. Then you can check what the status of that flag is after the loop, and react accordingly.

Comment: okay, i was thinking like that, maybe larave have a "magic" function :))

Comment: Yes, Laravel has a magic function :). Because you have `Collection` returned from the `Model` call, you can use Collection methods for filtering result. For instance `first` method [https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-first], if you pass your condition inside, will return the first element that passes your test or `null` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`mapToGroups`**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-maptogroups) collection method.

```php
$get = DateModel::get()
    ->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
        $nowTime = '02:00';

        if ($nowTime >= $item->start_time && $nowTime <= $item->end_time) {
            return ['in range time' => $item];
        } else {
            return ['not in range time' => $item];
        }
    });
```

**Result**

```php
array:2 [
  "in range time" => array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "day" => "Sunday"
      "start_time" => "01:00"
      "end_time" => "03:00"
    ]
  ]
  "not in range time" => array:2 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "day" => "Sunday"
      "start_time" => "13:00"
      "end_time" => "15:00"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "day" => "Sunday"
      "start_time" => "19:00"
      "end_time" => "21:00"
    ]
  ]
]
```